# ODE in which non-continuous function yields uniqueness of solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem
$$
\begin{cases}
y^\prime = f(x,y)\\
y(a) = b.
\end{cases}
$$

Do yo know any function $f$ that is *not continuous* for which we have uniqueness of solution for the IVP?

(One example is the function that is $f=2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f=0$ for $x=0$ (for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$) where the IVP condition is $y(0)=0$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have an example, I suppose you want one where $f$ depends on $y$ as well as $x$.
Take any function $Y(x)$ that is differentiable but $Y'$ is discontinuous, and let $f(x,y) = Y'(x) - Y(x) + y$